# Dynamic function name in AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Following is my `Pagination Directive`

```
angular.module('frontendApp')
    .directive('postsPagination', function() {
        return{
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<ul class="pagination">'+
            '<li ng-show="currentPage != 1"><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="getList(1)">&laquo;</a></li>'+
            '<li ng-show="currentPage != 1"><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="getList(currentPage-1)">&lsaquo; Prev</a></li>'+
            '<li ng-repeat="i in range" ng-class="{active : currentPage == i}">'+
            '<a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="getList(i)">{{i}}</a>'+
            '</li>'+
            '<li ng-show="currentPage != totalPages"><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="getList(currentPage+1)">Next &rsaquo;</a></li>'+
            '<li ng-show="currentPage != totalPages"><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="getList(totalPages)">&raquo;</a></li>'+
            '</ul>'
        };
    });
```

I want the function name in `ng-click` to be dynamic
i:e `ng-click = getList`

Comment: Hi Aparna,
Can you please elaborate, what exactly you mean by dynamic.

Comment: Hi, dynamic in the sense, the function name should be changable. Currently my function name is fixed.So i can't use the same directive for other pagination with different function.

Answer (score 0):

Look this: https://jsfiddle.net/n9KNv/14/

Use the $compiler for angular interpreting ng-click in directive. Like this

```
angular.module('frontendApp')
    .directive('postsPagination', function(){
        return{
            restrict: 'E',
            template:  $compile('<ul class="pagination">'+
            '<li ng-show="currentPage != 1"><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="getList(1)">&laquo;</a></li>'+
            '<li ng-show="currentPage != 1"><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="getList(currentPage-1)">&lsaquo; Prev</a></li>'+
            '<li ng-repeat="i in range" ng-class="{active : currentPage == i}">'+
            '<a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="getList(i)">{{i}}</a>'+
            '</li>'+
            '<li ng-show="currentPage != totalPages"><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="getList(currentPage+1)">Next &rsaquo;</a></li>'+
            '<li ng-show="currentPage != totalPages"><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="getList(totalPages)">&raquo;</a></li>'+
            '</ul>');
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the javascript `eval()` method.

> The eval function enables dynamic execution of JavaScript source code.

To turn a your function name string back into a javascript expression cyou can use the `eval()` method like so:

```
var dateFn = "Date(1971,3,8)";
var myDate;
eval("myDate = new " + dateFn + ";");

document.write(myDate);

// Output: Thu Apr 8 00:00:00 PDT 1971
```

[MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/12k71sw7(v=vs.94).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

directive.html

```
<ul class="pagination">
<li ng-show="currentPage != 1">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="getList(1)">&laquo;</a></li>
<li ng-show="currentPage != 1">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="getList(currentPage-1)">&lsaquo; Prev</a></li>
<li ng-repeat="i in range" ng-class="{active : currentPage == i}">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="getList(i)">{{i}}</a></li>
<li ng-show="currentPage != totalPages">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="getList(currentPage1)">Next &rsaquo;</a></li>
<li ng-show="currentPage != totalPages">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="getList(totalPages)">&raquo;</a></li>
```

controller1.js

```
angular
    .module('frontendApp')
    .controller('Ctrl1', function(){
       $scope.getList = function(){} // your implementation 1 here 
    });
```

controller2.js

```
angular
.module('frontendApp')
.controller('Ctrl2', function(){
   $scope.getList = function(){} // your other implementation here 
});
```

Now use the same html file at both places and just by changing the controller name ypu can have different implementations for the same function, thus reusing your template:

```
angular.module('frontendApp')
.directive('postsPagination', function() {
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'directive.html',
        controller: 'Ctrl1'
    };
});
angular.module('frontendApp')
.directive('someOther', function() {
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'directive.html',
        controller: 'Ctrl2'
    };
});
```